# google place api で意図したデータが取れない

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-cloud, google-api

## 問題

以下のurlでレビューと電話番号のデータを取ろうとしたのですが、電話番号とレビューの`text`,`rating`以外のほとんどの値がnilになってしまいます。ただ、urlを直接webで叩くと意図したjsonのデータが確認できます。
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id="PLACE ID"&fields=reviews,formatted_phone_number&key="api key"`
[リファレンス](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details)には、取れていないデータの説明書きの最後にif available.と記載されているのですが、これが何を意味しているかが分かりません。

取れているデータはあるので文法上のミスないのかなと思います。
また、Modelはapiを直接叩いて確認したデータを[quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/)というのを使って生成したのでタイポも考えにくいです。

```
struct Empty: Codable {
    let result: Result
    let status: String?
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Codable {
    let formattedPhoneNumber: String?
    let reviews: [Review]
}

// MARK: - Review
struct Review: Codable {
    let authorName: String?
    let authorurl: String?
    let language: String?
    let profilePhotourl: String?
    let rating: Int?
    let relativeTimeDescription, text: String?
    let time: Int?
}
```

jsonData (データをそのまんま見せていいのか不安になったので、実際のデータをxに置き換えています）

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "formatted_phone_number" : "xx-xxxx-xxxx",
      "reviews" : [
         {
            "author_name" : "xxxx",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/xxxxx/xxxxxxx/reviews",
            "language" : "xx",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://xxxxx.com/-xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 4,
            "relative_time_description" : "x か月前",
            "text" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx。",
            "time" : 1234567
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "xxxxxxxx",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/xxxxxxxx/reviews",
            "language" : "xx",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh6.ggpht.com/-xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "x 週間前",
            "text" : "xxxxxxxxx",
            "time" : 1234567
         }
      ]
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: 項目名に打ち間違いがあれば、その項目は取れなくなるので「タイポはない」と言う判断は誤りです。「urlを直接webで叩くと意図したjsonのデータが確認できます」と言うことなら、実際に取得したjsonデータを示してもらうと、何かわかることがあるかもしれません。「if available」と言うのは「利用可能であれば」の意味で、利用可能でない(どんな条件で利用可能になるかは分かりませんが)なら取れないこともあると言っているわけです。しかし、「urlを直接webで叩くと意図したjsonのデータが確認できます」と言うことですので、利用可能ではないと言う理由は考えにくいかと思います。

Comment: 「quicktypeというのを使って生成した」と言うことですが、私が試しにリファレンスのサイトにあるレスポンス例を編集してコード生成したところ、あなたがご質問に含めておられるコードとは随分違ったものが出てきました。オプションもいろいろあるようですし、「タイポ」ではないにしても、正しく動作する項目名にはなっていない可能性は高い、と言えるでしょう。「apiを直接叩いて確認したデータ」を示していただくことは出来ないのでしょうか?

Answer (score 0):

jsonData のご提示ありがとうございます。実際の中身をご提示いただけるまでは、何かの設定やオプションでキーが書き換えられると言う可能性も捨てきれなかったのですが、そんなこともなかったようです。

「text,rating以外のほとんどの値がnil」と言うことですが、現在のあなたのコードを使うと、`language`, `rating`, `text`, および`time`の各項目は取得できているのではないでしょうか?

これは、

**`Review`クラスのプロパティ名と全く同じキーがJSON中に存在していればデータが取れている**

と言うことを表しています。

一方データが取れていない方の項目ですが、`authorName`を取ってくるために必要な`"authorName"`なんてキーの項目はJSON中には存在しません。

`"authorurl"`も`"profilePhotourl"`も`"relativeTimeDescription"`もJSON中には存在しません。ですから、

**それらの項目が取れないのは当たり前**

と言うことになります。

---

### 対応法その1

**モデルのプロパティ名をJSONのキー名に完全に一致させる**

と言うのが一つの方法です。

```
struct PlacesAPIResponse: Codable {
    let result: Result
    let status: String?
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Codable {
    let formatted_phone_number: String?
    let reviews: [Review]
}

// MARK: - Review
struct Review: Codable {
    let author_name: String?
    let author_url: String?
    let language: String?
    let profile_photo_url: String?
    let rating: Int?
    let relative_time_description, text: String?
    let time: Int?
}
```

(`Empty`なんて型名はあまりにもあれなんで、書き換えています。)

ご紹介いただいたquicktypeサイトでは、この形式のSwiftコードを出力できるようなオプションは見つかりませんでした。他の類似のサイトを探すか、自分で手を入れないといけないでしょう。

ただ、Swiftでは、スネークケースの識別子は原則使用しませんので、コードがSwiftっぽくなくなってしまいます。あまりこの方法を好まれる方はいないかもしれません。

---

### 対応方法その2

**`CodingKeys`を明示して、プロパティ名とJSON側のキー名の対応を明記する**

と言う手もあります。

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - PlaceAPIResponse
struct PlaceAPIResponse: Codable {
    let result: Result?
    let status: String?
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Codable {
    let formattedPhoneNumber: String?
    let reviews: [Review]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case formattedPhoneNumber = "formatted_phone_number"
        case reviews
    }
}

// MARK: - Review
struct Review: Codable {
    let authorName: String?
    let authorURL: String?
    let language: String?
    let profilePhotoURL: String?
    let rating: Int?
    let relativeTimeDescription, text: String?
    let time: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case authorName = "author_name"
        case authorURL = "author_url"
        case language
        case profilePhotoURL = "profile_photo_url"
        case rating
        case relativeTimeDescription = "relative_time_description"
        case text, time
    }
}
```

このコードはquicktypeサイトで、Explicit CodingKey values in Codable typesと、Make all properties optionalをONにして生成したものそのままです。

ちなみに自動生成したコードでは`authorURL`や`profilePhotoURL`のように`URL`の部分が大文字に変換されました。ご質問で使用されているコードは手作業で一部変更されたのでしょうか?

なお、quicktypeサイトでそのまま使えそうな`CodingKeys`が生成されたのは、このExplicit CodingKey values in Codable typesオプションを指定した時だけでした。その他の場合には、使えもしない`CodingKeys`が出力されてしまいます。

ただし、ほとんどの項目名がスネークケースからキャメルケースへの機械的変換で済むのに、`CodingKeys`が指定されているのは、かえってコードが読みにくいと思われる方もいるでしょう。

---

## 対応法その3

- **モデルのプロパティ名をJSONのキー名から機械的に変換したものに完全に一致させる**
- **`JSONDecoder`で、`keyDecodingStrategy =  .convertFromSnakeCase`を指定する**

と言う手もあります。ご質問中には、`JSONDecoder`を使う部分のコードが示されていないので、以下はXcodeのPlaygroundなどで試せる形で記載しておきます。

```
import Foundation

let jsonText = #"""
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "formatted_phone_number" : "xx-xxxx-xxxx",
      "reviews" : [
         {
            "author_name" : "xxxx",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/xxxxx/xxxxxxx/reviews",
            "language" : "xx",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://xxxxx.com/-xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 4,
            "relative_time_description" : "x か月前",
            "text" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx。",
            "time" : 1234567
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "xxxxxxxx",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/xxxxxxxx/reviews",
            "language" : "xx",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh6.ggpht.com/-xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "x 週間前",
            "text" : "xxxxxxxxx",
            "time" : 1234567
         }
      ]
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
"""#

let jsonData = jsonText.data(using: .utf8)!

struct PlacesAPIResponse: Codable {
    let result: Result
    let status: String?
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Codable {
    let formattedPhoneNumber: String?
    let reviews: [Review]
}

// MARK: - Review
struct Review: Codable {
    let authorName: String?
    let authorUrl: String? //<- `authorurl`や`authorURL`ではダメ
    let language: String?
    let profilePhotoUrl: String? //<- 上記と同様
    let rating: Int?
    let relativeTimeDescription: String?
    let text: String?
    let time: Int?
}

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy =  .convertFromSnakeCase
    let response = try decoder.decode(PlacesAPIResponse.self, from: jsonData)
    print(response)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

`Review`のプロパティ名の一部`authorUrl`と`profilePhotoUrl`、それから`.convertFromSnakeCase`を指定している部分に注意して下さい。

---

対応法2の方は、`JSONDecoder`が理解できる変換規則に縛られずに自由にプロパティ名とJSONのキー名の対応が付けられるので、より自由度が高いと言えるでしょう。

ただ、このAPIのように綺麗にキャメルケースに変換できるキー名になっている場合は対応法3を好まれる人も多いかもしれません。

ご自身のコーディングスタイルに合わせて、どれかの方法を試してみて下さい。

Comment: 丁寧な解説本当にありがとうございます！！quick typeの設定でAcronym naming styleのところがLower Caseになっていました。。。
対応法その3で試してみたところ無事確認出来ました！ありがとうございます！！

Comment: @kokoroterada さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。「Other」側にそんなオプションが隠れていたのですね。気付いていませんでした。お役に立てたのであれば幸いです。